# Is there a way to escape the error and go to the next word?

Tags: python

I run this code and encounter errors below:
How can I escape the error and continue with the next wrod?

```
GLOVE_DATASET_PATH = 'glove.840B.300d.txt'

from tqdm import tqdm
import string
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(GLOVE_DATASET_PATH, encoding="utf8")
word_counter = 0
for line in tqdm(f):
  values = line.split()
  word = values[0]
  if word in dictionary:
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
  word_counter += 1
f.close()

print('Found %s word vectors matching enron data set.' % len(embeddings_index))
print('Total words in GloVe data set: %s' % word_counter)
```

The error message is ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.' on line ---> 12     coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')

Comment: Print the `line`, the content might not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress it:

```
from contextlib import suppress
with suppress(ValueError):
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
```

Comment: Maybe link to [definition and equivalent code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) in case OP just does not know `try/except`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This code works well and suppressed the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find out what is happening when something happens:

```
  if word in dictionary:
      try: 
          coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
      except:
          print(values[1:], type(values[1:]))
          coefs = 0
      embeddings_index[word] = coefs
```

This will print out what you got in return, that could not be converted and will also write a `0` in your list at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This works perfectly and resolved the problem. :)

Comment: If the answer is what you were looking for please accept it.